# Excel SqlBulkCopy works differently on local pc, and on application server?

Tags: c#, excel, sqlbulkcopy, oledbconnection

My application truncates a database table and fills it with the rows from an excel.

Using an excel file (2000 rows), below upload code inserts all the rows to database completely in my local pc (my development environment) and it did in the server too,  so I thought that I succesfully accomplished the task,

But then a user added 10 new row to my excel and tried to upload 2010 rows but except newly added 10 rows the 2000 row was inserted, So using that excel file with 2010 rows, If I upload it from the server database table populated with 2000 rows, and if I upload it using my working environment final table is 2010 rows.

Server and local application is exactly the same.
I tried the formatting etc too

**Edit Example Execution:** File MyRecords.xlsx is located in my desktop, now I connect to my application using

```
http://myserver/myapplication
```

and upload MyRecords.xlsx, then check count in database, it says 2361 records, then open visual studio and run my application (`http://localhost:58029/`) and upload MyRecords.xlsx and check database again it says 2362 records.

**Edit Example Execution 2:** My excel has 2160 lines, If I upload it, it inserts 2160 lines from both local and in server. If I remove 1000 thousand lines and upload it, now it inserts 1160 lines from local and from server as expected. Now If I re-add this 1000 lines and upload the excel, now if I did this process using local environment it works fine 2160 lines inserted, If server, 1160 lines inserted. So any modification on excel is not seen at the serverside, so are you sure this is the reason? –

```
    private void UploadData(string path, string dbTableName)
    {
        //Create connection string to Excel work book
        string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False";
        //Create Connection to Excel work book
        OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
        //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel

        excelConnection.Open();
        DataTable dbSchema = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null); //Get First Sheet Name
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [" + dbSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "]", excelConnection);

        OleDbDataReader dReader;
        dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ConnectionString);

        //Give your Destination table name
        sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = dbTableName;

        try
        {
            sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
            if(dbTableName == "TempTP")
            {
                SDatabaseManagerData.DatabaseManagerData.UpdateTP();
            }

            lbl_Error.Visible = true;
            lbl_Error.Text = "Database updated!";

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            lbl_Error.Visible = true;
            lbl_Error.Text = "Database updated edilemedi! Hata: " + ex.Message;
        }

        excelConnection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: What name is returned by dbSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() ?

Comment: Check to make absolutely sure that the file has the added records. I suspect that the problem is not with the code you have here, but that the user added the records and did not save or upload correctly. Can you verify that?

Comment: @D_Bester I am manually adding records to the excel, it works like select top(2361) from sheet1 in the server whatever I do, but for the same file it works select * from sheet1. Couldn't figure out still.

Comment: Are you suggesting it doesn't need to be saved? You don't seem to be answering that question. I think you are saying that you have an Excel workbook to which you are adding information. It doesn't matter how you add the information to the workbook (manually or otherwise) if your problem is about getting information out of the workbook.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the SQL as in select top(2361) as that is not hard coded. Rather your problem is with the process of adding records and then uploading the file to the server. Those two steps are critical to the success of your program so you want to make sure it's done right. I may well be missing something but I can't tell from the information you've supplied so far so keep trying.

Comment: Actually I wonder that what else I can do other than (ctrl + s) to save the file. I am not suggesting that it doesn't need to be saved,but what I am saying that "if it was not saved, it would not be working when I upload the excel file using the development environment" I believe that some kind of olddbcommand problem or maybe connectionstring problem is causing the issue, some kind of difference caused by hosting environment

Comment: Maybe the thing about saving the file seems to obvious to mention but you can never be sure about the users. Have you carefully checked the file at the "path" to make sure the user actually uploaded the file they thought they did? This might also seem to be obvious but hey it happens.

Comment: Since I developed the application, after user told me about the issue, I took the file and put it to my desktop, added 1 line to it and tried, it didn't see that new file, so I renamed the excel file and saved and tried again and no it didn't work too, again it inserted the same lines.

Comment: You say "it didn't see that new file" That's an interesting comment that suggests to me that the file is not where the program expects it to be.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34389/discussion-between-d-bester-and-hoy)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the table returned by GetOleDbSchemaTable did not include the all the data. Did the user add the rows below the table instead of within the table?

Check the name that is returned by `dbSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString()` Does that refer to the sheet or to a table name?

Edit: Also make sure that the user saved and uploaded the file correctly. Compare the Excel file with the database to make sure they match.

[How To Retrieve Schema Information by Using GetOleDbSchemaTable and Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309488)

Comment: I don't know what it returns in application server, but in development environment it returns "Sheet1$", which is the first sheet's name.

Comment: If it returned Sheet1$ then it should have taken the entire sheet. Did they save the file? Did they save it locally or in the correct location?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of "typeguessrow" functionality of excel.
Change registry set the typeguessrow from 8 to 0.

**Process**
1.type **regedit.exe** on command prompt and search for **typeguessrow**(press F3 to open search).
2. export registry as backup

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel]
"DisabledExtensions"="!xls"
"ImportMixedTypes"="Text"
"FirstRowHasNames"=hex:01
"AppendBlankRows"=dword:00000001
"TypeGuessRows"=dword:00000008
"win32"="C:\PROGRA~1\COMMON~1\MICROS~1\OFFICE12\ACEEXCL.DLL"

1. change **"TypeGuessRows"=dword:00000008** to **"TypeGuessRows"=dword:00000000**
2. import registry

Comment: I don't think this is the reason, here is an occurance. My excel has 2160 lines, If I upload it, it inserts 2160 lines from both local and in server. If I remove 1000 thousand lines and upload it, now it inserts 1160 lines from local and from server as expected. Now If I re-add this 1000 lines and upload the excel, now if I did this process using local environment it works fine 2160 lines inserted, If server, 1160 lines inserted. So any modification on excel is not seen at the serverside, so are you sure this is the reason?

Comment: yes because there is change in formatting. most probably dates. **"ImportMixedTypes"="Text"** and **"TypeGuessRows"=dword:00000000** with dates column formatted as date will solve your problem